# Add Open In ... option to ipad gallery?

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

I am trying to add my app to Open In ... option in iPad and I have added file type which supported by my app to Document types in Info.plist. This works on files open in Mail client and safari. Is there a way to add this to iPad gallery?.

Comment: "open in " works only for mail and safari

Comment: Sadly, for some unknown reason, Apple does not give anyone the option of opening 3rd party apps for images from the Photos app. The best thing is to use Copy from the Photos app and ensure your app supports the ability to paste an image from the pasteboard.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be helpful for future user's

you can't get Open in... option in gallery . But if you wan't to get that option in other app's , then you have make some changes in info.plist

e.g

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Images</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.image</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

this make your app to be listed in Open in... in other app's . And make sure that you have implemented

`(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation`

method in your AppDelegate to handle call back ..

Comment: This is not what i am looking for it think  @rmaddy is right is can not be done.